# Export to CSV ForEach

Tags: powershell

I'm not using PowerShell usually, so i was hoping someone can give me a hand with this.
I found this scrip in the network which shows all my powerapps and flows on my tenant per environment. I want to export the final results in .csv

```
    Import-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell
Add-PowerAppsAccount
$environments = Get-PowerAppEnvironment
$result = @()
ForEach($environment in $environments){
write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Apps In" $environment.DisplayName
write-host -ForegroundColor Black (Get-AdminPowerApp -EnvironmentName $environment.EnvironmentName |Select DisplayName | write-host -ForegroundColor Black )
write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Flows In" $environment.DisplayName
write-host -ForegroundColor Black (Get-AdminFlow -EnvironmentName $environment.EnvironmentName |Select DisplayName | write-host -ForegroundColor Black)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because both `Get-AdminPowerApp` and `Get-AdminFlow` can return multiple objects, you need to combine the DisplayNames in such a case with a character of your choosing.
Below I have used the semi-colon (`;`) for that, but you can also use a newline (`[environment]::NewLine`) if you want.

Instead of creating an array or list your loop adds items to, it is far easier to let PowerShell collect the data for you.

```
Import-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell
Add-PowerAppsAccount

$result = foreach ($environment in (Get-PowerAppEnvironment)) {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        'Environment' = $environment.DisplayName
        'Apps In'     = (Get-AdminPowerApp -EnvironmentName $environment.EnvironmentName).DisplayName -join ';'
        'Flows In'    = (Get-AdminFlow -EnvironmentName $environment.EnvironmentName).DisplayName -join ';'
    }
}

# display on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to Csv file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\Somewhere\PowerApps.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This one worked as you suggested, i just tested couple of one to see the difference, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Export-CSV with following results

```
Import-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell
Add-PowerAppsAccount
$environments = Get-PowerAppEnvironment
$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
ForEach($environment in $environments){
   $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Environment -NotePropertyValue $environment.DisplayName
   
   $appIn = Get-AdminPowerApp -EnvironmentName $environment.EnvironmentName |Select DisplayName
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Apps In" -NotePropertyValue $appIn

   $appOut = Get-AdminFlow -EnvironmentName $environment.EnvironmentName |Select DisplayName
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Flows In" -NotePropertyValue $appOut

   $table.Add($newRow)  | Out-Null
}
$table
```

Comment: But where should i add Export-Csv -Path so i can get all this results as csv? At the end of the script just exports an empty file with 3 columns but rows are empy

Comment: After the foreach.

Comment: I'm afraid is not working, any help 
$table
Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\KirilRadoslavov\Desktop\Exports\PowerAutomateDesktop\Test.csv

Comment: You  are missing the pipe after table : $table | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\KirilRadoslavov\Desktop\Exports\PowerAutomateDesktop\Test.csv

Comment: even with that mistake from my side, the exported file contains no rows. here is a [link]: (https://ibb.co/pbb1Zg2) to see what i get as export, otherwise, it looks like this in the original script that i've posted (https://ibb.co/H42MXv9)